# I am using WMS Decorations in GeoServer, I've added a scaleline but when I try to add options like transparency or measurement-system it does not work

Tags: xml, layout, geoserver, wms

[That is my xml file for the layout with the options I want to add included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIHFO.png)

When I add the options to the decoration element, it does not give me an error, the scaleline appears but not with the optiones I've added, it is like I don't have added it.

Comment: Does the log file show anything?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ian. The log file does not show anything, any error, any clue.

Comment: well what is the url you are using? and the name and location of your decotrator file (and the text of it, rather than a picture)

Comment: Hello Ian. This is my url: "http://www.serviciosgis.com/geoserver/gisviewer/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=gisviewer:fondo,tg04_capv_territorios&styles=&bbox=463435.23,4702192.17,603082.1649,4811578.68&width=512&height=401&format_options=layout:foo;dpi:150&srs=EPSG:25830&format=image/png" I am using and internal GeoServer of my company. The name of my file is foo.xml and it is located in layouts directoty inside data directory in my server (C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\geoserver\data\layouts). Thaks for your help, I really appreciated it